# Appointment fixing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, appointment

I want to select data between two given time(start_time,end_time) from two different column (start_time,end_time) based in given date and therapist_id in php mysql.

My database is showed below

```
appointment_id name    age email                appointment_date appointment_time appointment_endtime user_id therapist_id status
             4 testing  25 notjitendra@mail.com       2015-11-03         01:00:00            02:00:00       2           12 SEND
             3 testing  25 notjitendra@mail.com       2015-11-03         01:00:00            02:00:00       2           12 SEND
             2 testing  25 notjitendra@mail.com       2015-11-03         01:00:00            02:00:00       2           12 SEND
             1 testing  25 notjitendra@mail.com       2015-11-03         05:00:00            06:00:00       2           12 SEND
```

I am trying to write query like

```
"SELECT therapist_id, appointment_time, appointment_endtime 
 FROM appointment
 WHERE ((appointment_time BETWEEN '".$timee."' AND '".$end_time."' ) OR     
 (appointment_endtime BETWEEN '".$end_time."' AND '".$timee."') ) AND          
 therapist_id='".$_REQUEST['therapist_id']."' AND       
 appointment_date='".$_REQUEST['date']."'"
```

Comment: "give me proper solution" => please ?

Comment: "give me proper solution" => Can someone please help me getting on the right track?

Comment: 1. I can read those email addresses. So, if they're really sensitive, consider removing that image from wherever you uploaded it. 2. See normalization. It's obviously redundant to store client information in this table. 3. You don't really store 'age', do you? 4. Consder storing date and time as a single entity. It's more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
"SELECT therapist_id,appointment_time,appointment_endtime FROM appointment     WHERE appointment_time>='$timee' and appointment_endtime<='$end_time' 
AND therapist_id='".$_REQUEST['therapist_id']."' AND appointment_date='".$_REQUEST['date']."'"
```

Comment: I so want to schedule an appointment at `'; DELETE FROM appointment; --`. Do you think that date is still available?

Comment: ANSWER SELECT therapist_id,appointment_time,appointment_endtime FROM appointment WHERE ((appointment_time BETWEEN '".$timee."' AND '".$end_time."' ) OR (appointment_endtime BETWEEN '".$timee."' AND '".$end_time."') ) AND therapist_id='".$_REQUEST['therapist_id']."' AND appointment_date='".$_REQUEST['date']."'